# how to specify location of nuget packages when package restore is enabled?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I am working on a .net solution and use nuget for my package management. I have selected the option to "Enable Nuget Package Restore" so that the nuget packages not checked in to source control.

Prior to this I had a nuget.config file at the same level as the solution where I included to following enabling me to specify the location of the nuget packages.

```
<settings> 
  <repositoryPath>..\Build\NuGetPackages\</repositoryPath> 
</settings>
```

Since I enabled the nuget package restore, this is no longer working. I tried to update the config file within the .nuget generated folder but that does not work either.

So where I am going wrong and how can I specify the location of the packages folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the next property in `your-solution\.nuget\NuGet.targets` file:

```
<PackagesDir>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SolutionDir), "packages"))</PackagesDir>
```

Or the same property, but in group below if you are using Mono.

Comment: Thanks for this - it was what I was trying but the change was not being picked until I restarted Visual Studio for some reason

Answer (score 6):

When you enable nuget package restore, there is a NuGet.Config file in the .nuget folder.

Here is a copy showing the path to my libs folder.  You can modify yours to match your path.  I think its a little cleaner than the already selected answer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="../../libs/packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at the nuget 2.1 release notes here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1, where there is a new setting added to nuget.config to specify package folder location

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key=" repositoryPath" value=" C:\myteam\teampackages" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```