# Can't specify nuget package folder location

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, visual-studio-2015

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737566/how-to-specify-location-of-nuget-packages-when-package-restore-is-enabled) and [nuget docs](https://docs.nuget.org/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.1#Specify-packages-Folder-Location).
 But I can't get it to work.

This is my configuration:

I have a "File/New Project" Console Application, My project folder is:

```
c:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1
    ... Program.cs and source files
c:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.sln
c:\ConsoleApplication1\nuget.config
```

My `nuget.config` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="c:\blah" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Now, when I install or restore packages, they are always installed to a `packages` folder inside my project's folder

I'm using VisualStudio 2015 RC

Comment: This is a bug in NuGet 3.0. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/626